# Simple socket client and server program not working

Tags: java

I am quite new to java and learning how to create a simple server/client echo program, however it doesn't seem to be running properly. Instead, when I run the server and then the client it gets stuck after "Network is reading...", but the server doesn't actually return anything. Any help is appreciated, below is my server and client code.

Client:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        while ((input = s.next())!= null){
        //  String input = s.next();

            out.println(input);

            System.out.println("Networking is reading....");

            System.out.println(in.readLine());
            System.out.println("please");
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        //  String line = in.readLine();
            out.println(line);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Did you [do a Google search at all](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)?

Comment: what do you think you are writing to the client?  Also not sure why you are using and looping on `Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: This is a great question that i would also like the answer to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true );
```

- and do this on both client and server

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)), a true here will enable auto flush.

Enabling autoflush is great for when you need to send data line by line.

**alternative**

The alternative would be manually flushing the buffer to the wire.

```
out.flush();
```

The reason for this is that you are writing into a buffer on the local machine - it will only send a frame of data when you flush that buffer.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!!